# Maven build failed with GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to build the project with the following command

```
mvn clean install
```

But every-time its end with memory issue ,then i run same command with `-X` option and it end with follwoing detail error

> [ERROR] GC overhead limit exceeded -> [Help 1]
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
>           at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332)
>           at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:124)
>           at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:649)
>           at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:202)
>           at aQute.bnd.osgi.Clazz.parseReference(Clazz.java:1807)
>           at aQute.bnd.osgi.Clazz.parseReferences(Clazz.java:1774)
>           at aQute.bnd.osgi.Clazz.parseDescriptor(Clazz.java:1756)
>           at aQute.bnd.osgi.Clazz.referTo(Clazz.java:1727)
>           at aQute.bnd.osgi.Clazz.parseClassFileData(Clazz.java:759)
>           at aQute.bnd.osgi.Clazz.parseClassFileData(Clazz.java:509)
>           at aQute.bnd.osgi.Clazz.parseClassFileWithCollector(Clazz.java:494)
>           at aQute.bnd.component.AnnotationReader.getDef(AnnotationReader.java:134)
>           at aQute.bnd.component.AnnotationReader.getDefinition(AnnotationReader.java:130)
>           at aQute.bnd.component.DSAnnotations.analyzeJar(DSAnnotations.java:126)
>           at aQute.bnd.osgi.Analyzer.doPlugins(Analyzer.java:664)
>           at aQute.bnd.osgi.Analyzer.analyze(Analyzer.java:216)
>           at aQute.bnd.osgi.Builder.analyze(Builder.java:387)
>           at aQute.bnd.osgi.Analyzer.calcManifest(Analyzer.java:694)
>           at aQute.bnd.osgi.Builder.build(Builder.java:108)
>           at org.apache.felix.bundleplugin.BundlePlugin.buildOSGiBundle(BundlePlugin.java:972)
>           at org.apache.felix.bundleplugin.BundlePlugin.execute(BundlePlugin.java:467)
>           at org.apache.felix.bundleplugin.BundlePlugin.execute(BundlePlugin.java:384)
>           at org.apache.felix.bundleplugin.BundlePlugin.execute(BundlePlugin.java:375)
>           at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
>           at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307) [ERROR]
>   [ERROR] [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible
>   solutions, please read the following articles: [ERROR] [Help 1]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/OutOfMemoryError

So i tried for the cause and solution of the above exception and added below lines inside parent pom.xml file of the project but still same issue

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    [...]
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <fork>true</fork>
          <meminitial>512m</meminitial>
          <maxmem>1048m</maxmem>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    [...]
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

then i added

```
MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx1024M -Xss128M -XX:MetaspaceSize=512M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1024M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled"
```

inside the System variable section of Environment variable but this also not helping.I am using Windows 10 and Java version 8.

Can someone tell what will be solution ?

Comment: Have you tried max heap configs bigger than 1g. Also it looks like it is caused by felix maven plugin, try newer versions if it exist

Comment: @SilverShroud Yes in office with another machine i tried 2048 there also i was getting same issuue.Do you mean latest version of maven?

Comment: Please try with more memory like `-Xmx4096` and see if it works..? Furthermore check if you are using the most recent version of the felix-bundle-plugin..?

Comment: I mean this https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.felix/maven-bundle-plugin

Answer (score 3):

Adding these System variables will fix the issue

```
MAVEN_OPTS = -Xmx2048M -Xss128M -XX:MaxPermSize=2048M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
```

This can be added in Environment variable.

[image]

Comment: I had same issue, this helped me but with 8GB not 2, and 512 XSS

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, I solved the `GC overhead limit exceeded` issue, by modifying the environment `MAVEN_OPTS` variable value with:

```
-Xmx1024M -Xss128M -XX:MetaspaceSize=512M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1024M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
```

Comment: Depend on System Memory.